# Literature on Clifford modules

Tags: clifford-algebras, graded-rings-modules

I encountered Clifford modules in the book [Heat Kernels and Dirac Operators](https://link.springer.com/book/9783540200628). I am particularly interested in the definition of the isomorphism
$$\mathrm{End}(E)\cong C(V)\otimes \mathrm{End}_{C(V)}(E)$$
and the proof of the formula
$$\forall a\in C(V):\forall b\in \mathrm{End}_{C(V)}(E):\mathrm{Str}_E(a\otimes b)=(-2i)^{n/2}\sigma_n(a)\mathrm{Str}_{E/S}(b)$$
on page $146$. [Nicolaescu's notes](https://www3.nd.edu/%7Elnicolae/ind-thm.pdf) have been helpful, but I still have some open questions (e.g. what if $E$ is not complex) and I would like to read as much complementary literature as possible.